# Clustered Index?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustered-index

I have a logtable with (shortened for example) these columns:

```
user | time | uniqueid | msg
```

And there is a Primary Key on

```
user,time,uniqueid
```

and a Clustered Index on

```
user
```

Now the only three things that are done with this table are:

- insert an entry
- delete all entries older than x
- select entries for a user (max 1k at a time)

The selects happen rarely, the inserts happen all the time, and deleting is once per night.

If I understand correctly, the clustered Index will make the select very fast.
Because of the amount of data I noticed that deleting will take a very long time, and i guess that this is even worse because of the clustered Index. Is this correct? Also it might as well be making the inserts alot slower (but the numbers are small at a time, so this might not be noticed so easily)

My Idea would be:

- setting the Clustered Index to time
- as the primary key is never really used (nothing referes to this table or anything) would it make sense to just drop it and create another Index on user for the selects?

What is the best way to optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I would use an artificial primary key, but for a log table this doesn't really seem to make much sense unless you've omitted a requirement where you deal with individual log records.  In that case, it makes more sense to me to maintain your primary key using a non-clusted index with the columns in the order you specify.  Change the clustered index to be on time instead of on user.  The selects on user can use the index defined by your primary key and, while slowing down some, should still be reasonably fast as they can use an index scan instead of a table scan.  Since user is the first column, that should be fairly fast even though the rows are no longer contiguous.  Making the clustered index on time will dramatically speed up the deletes and likely reduce fragmentation as well.  Since you're still only maintaining two indexes, it shouldn't affect your insert performance.  In fact it may improve since the structure of the table will more closely mirror the way the data is inserted.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions:

- Keep the clustered index on user; this will yield the good select performance. Adding time to your clustered index would probably also improve select performance as you are likely selecting the most recent records (time), right?
- Your delete is slow because you are not indexing time; create a new index on time.
- Inserting might be a little slow, but if it isn't happening too often, then I wouldn't be too worried about it.

During peak usage, how many inserts are you seeing per hour? Selects? Also, what is uniqueid? Is it a GUID?

Comment: as stated above .. selects happen very rarely (maybe like up to 20 times per day or less) so this isnt really  important. If it takes twice as long - so be it. Inserts happen all the time, depending on the customer maybe up to 10-20 times per second. Even small amounts of approvement here make a big difference.

Comment: With inserts being so frequent, I would add a new column that is int, identity, and primary key and cluster on that column; this should yield the best insert results (no page splits) and minimize space/memory usage. I would make two indexes: time and user+time.

Answer (score 0):

If the `UniqueId` is really unique, as its name implies - **that** would be the **ideal candidate** as the primary key, in my opinion!

As for clustered key - I normally advocate strongly to follow the NUSE principle - narrow, unique, static, ever-increasing. And that seems to fit the `UniqueID` best, here. So that's definitely one option. This is usually a big concern if you have lots of nonclustered indices, too - which you don't, here, so you might choose a different clustered index in this case.

You seem to have two main operations:

- select by `user`
- delete based on `time`

So either of those two will be a good candidate for the clustering key. If you leave your clustering key on `user` then selecting by user will be fast - you'll need an additional nonclustered index on `time` to speed up your deletes.